# Where should I ask research/publication related questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

A lot of time I have research related questions (which are not programming related).

> TCS covers a wide variety of topics
>   including algorithms, data structures,
>   computational complexity, parallel and
>   distributed computation, probabilistic
>   computation, quantum computation,
>   automata theory, information theory,
>   cryptography, program semantics and
>   verification, machine learning,
>   computational biology, computational
>   economics, computational geometry, and
>   computational number theory and
>   algebra. Work in this field is often
>   distinguished by its emphasis on
>   mathematical technique and rigor.

My questions are neither TCS nor Math related. They are mostly related to OS, Networking,  Computer Vision or research in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general computer-related topics, you could ask on **[Super User](http://www.superuser.com/)**. Operating systems, networking, computer vision, etc. would all be on-topic there.

Certain ones of these questions might be better asked on **[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)**.

And of course, as you suspected, research-related questions that are about *programming* should be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/), and those about computer science in general (*without* any code) probably belong on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). Questions that on the half way between them, could be asked on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Questions about research from academical point of view can be asked on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq).

But it's fairly difficult to give a one-size-fits-all answer here. You really have to make these decisions on a case-by-case basis. The important thing is that you make a reasonable effort to ask the question on the appropriate site. If that site's community disagrees with you, they can migrate the question elsewhere. Try not to be offended or upset by a migration: this isn't intended as an insult to the asker, but rather simply a way to move good questions to a place they are more likely to be answered. With as many different Stack Exchange sites as we have now, it's almost impossible that anyone is knowledgeable about what's considered on-topic for *all* of them!